# How to consume and produce messages to Azure SQL DB using Camel

Tags: apache-camel, azure-sql-database, spring-jdbc, debezium

I have a usecase where I need to replicate data for a specific duration from one Azure SQL DB (subscription1) to another Azure SQL DB (supbscription2).

> The source DB has live data with continuous inserts, updates and
> deletes possibility. Henceforth, we will miss the updates while
> performing DB copy operations.

For consuming the messages, I am considering to use [Debizium SQL Server Connector](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/debezium-sqlserver-component.html), but this component

> **supports only the consumer functionality**

Which camel component can I use to produce the same event to the destination DB ??

-Srikant

Comment: If it just replicating the data why not use Azure SQL Db transactional replication. It would be easy and cheap to setup and run. It is a feature of the database.

Comment: Thanks  for the input, the replication feature is available as a public preview option only for Azure SQL managed Instance, but not for Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 1):

you can use one of the available Camel Kafka Connector implementations

- https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/latest/connectors/camel-jdbc-kafka-sink-connector.html
- https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/latest/connectors/camel-sql-kafka-sink-connector.html

If you don't you use Kafka Connect but plain Camel then just use respective Camel components.

Comment: Thanks,I was also thinking about camel-sql and camel-jdbc. Let me also consider the kafka connect flavour.

Comment: Hi,
Does these components have HA by default or do I need to use the camel clustering to achieve it ?
camel debezium sql server connector
camel-jdbc
camel-sql

-Regards
Srikant Mantha